# How can I automate the generation of this dynamic-programming graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I would like to draw the following dynamical programming graph.  I believe it could be sped by using the `foreach` syntax.

[image]

The code I have started to write is

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x/\y/\lab in {0/0/5, 1/1/6, 2/2/10, 3/3/7, 4/2/8, 5/1/10, 6/0/11,
    5/-1/9, 4/-2/7, 3/-3/6, 2/-2/9, 1/-1/7, 0/0/}{
    \draw (\x, \y) -- ??
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The issue is I need to index the next point so it goes `(x_1, y_1) -- (x_1, y_2) node[font = \small, pos = .5, fill = white, inner sep = .01] {\lab};`
How can this be done?

Then I will have to create other `foreach` loops to cut across.  Is there a way to do this entire process in one loop?  If so, how, because I don't see how can I do it.

Comment: Is it a multi-stage graph problem?????

Comment: @subhamsoni no it is an optimization problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one possible `\foreach` approach that lets you specify the weights row-wise and then the weights column-wise.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{rowcount}
\newcounter{columncount}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{scope}[rotate=-45]
  % rows
  \foreach[count=\y from 0] \W in {% row-wise weights
    {7,8,6},
    {8,8,12},
    {6,9,7},
    {7,8,10}%
  }{
    \stepcounter{rowcount}
    \foreach \w [count=\x, remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0)] in \W
      \draw (\lastx,\y) -- (\x,\y)
        node[above,pos=0.5] {\w};
  }
  % columns
  \foreach[count=\x from 0] \W in {% column-wise weights
    {5,6,10},
    {7,10,5},
    {10,5,6},
    {7,9,11}%
  }{
    \stepcounter{columncount}
    \foreach \w [count=\y, remember=\y as \lasty (initially 0)] in \W
      \draw (\x,\lasty) -- (\x,\y)
        node[above,pos=0.5] {\w};
  }
  \fill (0,0) circle (0.1em) node[below left] {A};
  \fill ({\value{columncount}-1},{\value{rowcount}-1}) circle (0.1em) node[below right] {B};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know LaTeX has some programming ability.  Is LaTeX able to find the cheapest path if those weights are cost?

Comment: So... you want an implementation of a dynamic-programming algorithm in LaTeX? That would deserve an entirely new question...

Comment: I guess it is feasible, and you might get a satisfactory answer, but I'm feeling too lazy to look into it right now `:)`