# Dynamic programming of cheapest cost in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming

From [How can I automate the generation of this dynamic-programming graph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172146/tikz-dynamic-programming-graph#172164), Jubobs helped develop a `foreach` scheme to draw the paths.  I was wondering if LaTeX can find the cheapest path by implementing dynamic programming.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{rowcount}
\newcounter{columncount}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{scope}[rotate=-45]
    % rows
    \foreach[count=\y from 0] \W in
    {{7,8,6},{8,8,8},{6,9,7},{7,8,10}} % row-wise weights
    {
      \stepcounter{rowcount}
      \foreach \w [count=\x, remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0)] in \W
        \draw (\lastx,\y) -- (\x,\y)
          node[above,pos=0.5] {\w};
    }
    % columns
    \foreach[count=\x from 0] \W in
    {{5,6,10},{7,10,5},{10,5,6},{7,9,11}} % column-wise weights
    {
      \stepcounter{columncount}
      \foreach \w [count=\y, remember=\y as \lasty (initially 0)] in \W
        \draw (\x,\lasty) -- (\x,\y)
          node[above,pos=0.5] {\w};
  }
  \fill (0,0) circle (0.1em) node[below left] {A};
  \fill ({\value{columncount}-1},{\value{rowcount}-1}) circle (0.1em) node[below right] {B};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1. Does LaTeX have this ability?
2. If it does, how is something like this done?

Comment: To be honest, I'd get the shortest path in another programming language than TeX if I were you.

Comment: @Jubobs I know that can be done.  I was curious about LaTeX's abilities.

Comment: @dustin Before we look for the ability of LaTeX or TeX, we must remember that LaTeX/TeX is not programming language per se, though some programming is definitely possible, which makes it powerful. It is a document preparation system. So, why make your life difficult trying to use a document preparation system which can be easily solved using a programming language? And once you have found the answer, why not use LaTeX for beautiful presentation of your results?

Comment: The [sagetex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/) package gives you the ability to tap into the Sage CAS. Shortest path is discussed [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/distances_all_pairs.html). Using the `sagetex` package would allow the calculations to be done during the LaTeX compilation rather than having to do work with a separate program "outside" of your tex document. [Sagemath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) gives you the access to the Sage CAS without having to install it to your computer.

Comment: So you expect quite some knowledge of nontrivial optimization schemes?