# Two identical diagrams inserted with subcaption box come out at different scales

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, subcaption

I have two diagrams that are 100% identical except for a red line in the other one.  However, when they are included in a figure as two subfigures with `subcapionbox`, the one with the red line is scaled down.

My set up for the figure is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin = .5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = parens, labelsep = space, font = small}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\newcounter{columncount}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Problem}{\includestandalone[width = 3in]{exam2prob5}}
\quad
\subcaptionbox{Solution}{\includestandalone[width = 3in]{exam2prob5sol}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

My two standalone files are:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{rowcount}
\newcounter{columncount}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{scope}[rotate=-45]
  % rows
  \foreach[count=\y from 0] \W in {% row-wise weights
    {7,8,6},
    {8,8,8},
    {6,9,7},
    {7,8,10}%
  }{
    \stepcounter{rowcount}
    \foreach \w [count=\x, remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0)] in \W
      \draw (\lastx,\y) -- (\x,\y)
        node[above,pos=0.5] {\w};
  }
  % columns
  \foreach[count=\x from 0] \W in {% column-wise weights
    {5,6,10},
    {7,10,5},
    {10,5,6},
    {7,9,11}%
  }{
    \stepcounter{columncount}
    \foreach \w [count=\y, remember=\y as \lasty (initially 0)] in \W
      \draw (\x,\lasty) -- (\x,\y)
        node[above,pos=0.5] {\w};
  }
  \fill (0,0) circle (0.1em) node[below left] {A};
  \fill ({\value{columncount}-1},{\value{rowcount}-1}) circle (0.1em) node[below right] {B};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and Solution

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{rowcount}
\newcounter{columncount}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{scope}[rotate=-45]
  % rows
  \foreach[count=\y from 0] \W in {% row-wise weights
    {7,8,6},
    {8,8,8},
    {6,9,7},
    {7,8,10}%
  }{
    \stepcounter{rowcount}
    \foreach \w [count=\x, remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0)] in \W
      \draw (\lastx,\y) -- (\x,\y)
        node[above,pos=0.5] {\w};
  }
  % columns
  \foreach[count=\x from 0] \W in {% column-wise weights
    {5,6,10},
    {7,10,5},
    {10,5,6},
    {7,9,11}%
  }{
    \stepcounter{columncount}
    \foreach \w [count=\y, remember=\y as \lasty (initially 0)] in \W
      \draw (\x,\lasty) -- (\x,\y)
        node[above,pos=0.5] {\w};
  }
  \fill (0,0) circle (0.1em) node[below left] {A};
  \fill ({\value{columncount}-1},{\value{rowcount}-1}) circle (0.1em) node[below right] {B};
  \draw[red, thick] (0, 0) -- (0, 2) -- (1, 2) -- (1, 3) -- (3, 3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The standalone image was an answer to a previos question in [How can I automate the generation of this dynamic-programming graph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172146/how-can-i-automate-the-generation-of-this-dynamic-programming-graph)

The red line I added was

```
\draw[red, thick] (0, 0) -- (0, 2) -- (1, 2) -- (1, 3) -- (3, 3);
```

The pdf produces:
[image]

If I comment out the first `subcaptionbox`, the second image is then regular size.

[image]

Also, there is space available for both images:

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to find out what's going on if you made your example completely self-contained, even if that means reusing code from that other question of yours.

Comment: @Jubobs I will add it when I get back from the gym then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A smaller MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\newcounter{columncount}
\begin{document}
\includestandalone[width=3in]{exam2prob5}
\includestandalone[width=3in]{exam2prob5sol}
\end{document}
```

The preamble of the included `.tex` files is *not* executed, when it is embedded by `\includestandalone`. In the updated question you have now added the missing lines

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\newcounter{columncount}
```

to the main file.

The documents `exam2prob5(sol).tex` are using a global resource, the counters `rowcount` and `columncount`. They are *not* reset after the image, thus the second included document work with value `4` instead of `0` for both counters.
And these counters influence the size of the TikZ drawings.

Therefore there are two possibilities for fixing:

- Reset the counters inside the files `exam2prob5(sol).tex` at the start of the `tikzpicture` environment:

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \setcounter{rowcount}{0}
    \setcounter{columncount}{0}
  ```
- Or do it in the main file between the included documents:

  ```
  \subcaptionbox{Problem}{\includestandalone[width = 3in]{exam2prob5}}
  \quad
  \setcounter{rowcount}{0}%
  \setcounter{columncount}{0}%
  \subcaptionbox{Solution}{\includestandalone[width = 3in]{exam2prob5sol}}
  ```

Comment: Just out of curiosity why does a counter affect the tikz picture size?

Comment: @dustin: The coordinate for `B` depends on `rowcount` and `columncount`. Larger values move it to the right, the width of the image increases and `width=3in` scales it down.